# Is there a way to get a current directory of a nautilus window?

Tags: linux, bash, nautilus

I'm opening a nautilus window from my bash script with `nautilus --new-window .`

How can I keep reading the currently open directory (even after navigating somewhere)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dbus-monitor` to watch for related events when you change the current folder in any tab of any nautilus window:

```
dbus-monitor "
  type='signal',
  interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',
  path='/org/freedesktop/FileManager1',
  member='PropertiesChanged'" |
  awk -F '"' '
    $2 ~ "^/org/gnome/Nautilus/window/[[:digit:]]+$" {
      window = $2
      sub(".*/", "", window)
      tab = 0
      next
    }
    window && /string / {
      print window"."++tab": "$2
      next
    }
    tab {window = 0}'
```

prints something like:

```
2.1: file:///export/home/stephane/Desktop/untitled%20folder
2.2: file:///export/home/stephane/Downloads
1.1: trash:///
```

(where `2.1` for instance means 2<sup>nd</sup> window, 1<sup>st</sup> tab) every time I change folder in any tab of any nautilus window.